# How to upload images from asp.net application to image server?

Tags: asp.net

I have two servers.One for web app and another for images storage .I have no idea how to upload images from web app to image server.

webservice or ftp or others?

Answer (score 0):

if you have sql server instance running on [Image Server], can't you use database running beneath it ? You'll need Public IP Address in order to access Server. Make sure you can connect to this DB from any other sql server management studio.

But for security reasons, i recommend to build web service/api & configure it on Image Server, which serves all requests made from your webapp.